# Svelte: 'import ... =' can only be used in TypeScript files

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

I was getting this error when trying to import a component into another one in the Svelte Javascript framework. In case anyone else receives this error I found the solution.

```
import Modal './Modal.svelte'; //imports another component for use
```

Answer (score 1):

I was missing off the FROM keyword in the import statement.

```
import Modal from './Modal.svelte'; //imports another component for use
```

Don't bother installing Flow language as suggested across the web, it's just a syntax issue.